# Installing python 3 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, anaconda

I had to install python 3.4.1 on my Mac OS 10.9.4 but it doesn't get picked up. 
First I installed [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads#34) python distribution and when I check conda It shows that I have python 3.4.1 installed on my macbook

```
 khurramsmacbook:~ kmajeed$ conda info 

   Current conda install:

             platform : osx-64
        conda version : 3.5.5
       python version : 3.4.1.final.0
     root environment : /Users/kmajeed/anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : /Users/kmajeed/anaconda
     envs directories : /Users/kmajeed/anaconda/envs
        package cache : /Users/kmajeed/anaconda/pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

But running following commands in terminal shows that I have python 2.7.5 installed

```
khurramsmacbook:~ kmajeed$ which python
/usr/bin/python
khurramsmacbook:~ kmajeed$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
khurramsmacbook:~ kmajeed$
```

I have also set up my $PATH variable using .bash_profile

```
khurramsmacbook:~ kmajeed$ $PATH
-bash: /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/kmajeed/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: just specify python3 when you want to use python3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2.7.5 is probably the one that comes pre-installed with OS X.

What you can do is invoke programs with `python3.4` instead of `python`.
In scripts use this as the first line;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
```

In a shell (for scripts without the executable bit set and without the shebang-line above) use;

```
python3.4 <scriptname>
```

The `python` in `/usr/bin` might be a symbolic link to `python2.7`. And you *could* replace that with a symbolic link to `python3.4`. But I would *not* recommend that because it will break existing programs that were written for Python 2.7 because of the incompatibilities between Python2 and Python 3.

Comment: As a note, you can also use `/usr/bin/env python3`. Thanks for the handy trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run Python 3.4.1 when you enter `python` in Terminal, the following line should be in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

The shell searches your `PATH` in order, so with your current setting it's still looking in `/usr/bin` first. With the new setting, it will look in `/Users/kmajeed/anaconda/bin` first.

Comment: using the path option you mentioned will it break other programs that are trying to access 2.7 as mentioned by Roland Smith

Comment: @KhurramMajeed it shouldn't, as those programs most likely refer to `/usr/bin/python` directly. Check in your `~/anaconda/bin` directory and see if there is a `python3` executable. If there is, then use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have Anaconda on your PATH, but it's not first, so the system Python in /usr/bin gets picked up first. Edit your `~/.profile` with something like what MattDMo suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.3 interpreter should be in the same Directory as python. You just have to A) Change the symbolic link (Not the best choice). B) make a new link that points to python 3 or C) you can use IDLE. IDLE is an ok IDE with a CMD line interface. But its nice because all you have to do is run IDLE and not have to make links or anything. IDLE is also supported by Python as well. The Link for download is here: https://www.python.org/download/